# Finding the right terminology for a dictionary table

Tags: sql, terminology, rdbms, database

My concern is about what I currently call "dictionary tables", that are database tables
containing a list of controlled vocabulary.

Let's use an example: 
Suppose you have a table **User** containing fields:

- user_id : primary key
- first_name
- last_name
- user_type_id : foreign key to the UserType table

and another table **UserType**  with just two fields:

- user_type_id : primary key
- name : the name/value of a particular type of user.

For instance, the **UserType** table may contain (1, Administrator), (2, PowerUser), (3, Normal)...

My question is: what is the canonical term for a table like **UserType**, that only contains a list of (dictinct) words. 
I want to publish some code that help managing this kind of tables, but first I have to name them !

Thanks for your help.

**Current state of thought:**
For now I feel **Lookup** Tables is a good term. It is also used with the same meaning in these posts:

- http://dbix-class.35028.n2.nabble.com/RFC-Component-for-Lookup-tables-td3504085.html
- http://tonyandrews.blogspot.de/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html
- [Lookup Tables Best Practices: DB Tables... or Enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433490/lookup-tables-best-practices-db-tables-or-enumerations)

The only problem is that **lookup** table is also sometimes used to name a *junction* table.

Comment: I'd call it a lookup table.  Not sure if that's the accepted term or not.

Comment: +1 to Lookup Table. I'd call it that too. [My answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12251008/1431750) was for the values in it which can then be called Lookup Values rather than Candidate Keys.

Comment: Physically, that would be called a lookup table or metadata. What you're actually building with a series of these things would be a data dictionary.

Comment: @KarlForner please refer to the down vote/up vote FAQ. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 1):

I often see that list of words as the domain of a function (the set of input values allowed), so I call them Domain Tables. But it´s from a mathematical point of view.

**EDIT**

See:

- [Data Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_domain)
- [Domain of a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function)

Comment: thanks. That makes sense, but if you are the only one to use it that kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: Everybody should know what the domain of a function is ;)

Comment: Why the downvote? A domain is a valid RDBMS term for the range of values for a column (or similar columns) e.g. Yes/No,True/False.

Comment: Sorry, was just to discard Domain from the candidates.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with SQL developers, the stronger their background in relational theory, the less likely they are to use terms like "lookup table", "validation table", or "dictionary table".

Instead, they just call them tables. Why?

For you, the important part seems to be tables that

- contain only one text column, or
- contain only one text column and an id number, or
- contain only one text column and a short text code, and
- the primary key is used as the target for foreign key references.

If you think about it for a while, the only thing that distinguishes these tables from others is the number of columns. Relational theory distinguish relations by the number of columns, and I don't feel the need for distinctions like that in SQL, either.

- *Every* candidate key implements a controlled vocabulary in this sense--the key (and all the other applicable constraints) provide the mechanism that controls the "vocabulary".
- Every candidate key can be used as the target for a foreign key reference, regardless of how many candidate keys a table has, regardless of how many columns a candidate key has, and regardless of whether any of the candidate keys are used as foreign key references today.
- Many such tables only *start* their life as "lookup" tables. A year down the road, someone discovers the need to store more information. After you add one or two more columns, is it still a "lookup" table, or not?

Comment: It is not the only thing that distinguishes these tables from others. The number of rows is finite, and often quite small, and they are quite stable (few changes), making them perfect targets for caching for instance. In my application I have at least 10 such tables.

Comment: The number of rows and stability might just be a coincidence. A table of country names would have around 400 rows, but one for city names might have more than 35,000 rows.

Comment: You make a good point. What to call these things depends largely on the target audience. Lookup table might mean a lot to a developer but be meaningless for a user (ditto other terms like domain).

Comment: @catcall: you are right, my intended use is to control the vocabulary, and to avoid hard-coded strings in code.

Comment: @dee: the target audien is developers, I want to name a perl package.

Answer (score 0):

As a C coder I'd say that this table looks really like an `enum` (or enumeration). It exhaustively defines acceptable values and links an automatically given integer to a name (and vice-versa).

*And as a SO user I'd say this question really looks a little too open as I don't think there is one unique canonical name...*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd just like to know the terms people use, so that I can lookup documentation and publish under an approprite name. And call a cat a cat, or a pussycat (I do not know if the translation from French works).

Comment: As a French coder, I see what you mean ^^ But seriously I think `enum` (which I really use) precisely describes both what it is and how it is used.

Comment: I agree enum seems quite good, but I'm waiting to see if there's a community accepted term. Lookup could work too, maybe even better.

Comment: I must confess, I've never come across enums (in the programming sense) in any of the RDBMSs I've used but it would be a very welcome addition.

Comment: [MysQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html) have an enum data type. But that's just for columns and can't replace an "enum" table.

Comment: I use it a lot to map with my java enums but it's not so useful as you can't easily extends mysql enums and you can't reuse an enum in different tables or columns (at least for MySQL, don't know for PostreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is commonly called a Data Dictionary

Comment: Are you sure ? Doing a quick search gives me http://database-programmer.blogspot.de/2008/06/using-data-dictionary.html and http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/D/data_dictionary.html that both disagree...

Comment: That's not what a data dictionary is. +1 @KarlForner

Comment: They're both correct. When I was a DBA, the file manifest was indeed also called the data dictionary. Like a lot of things in IT, there are that many terms/acronyms where the meaning depends on the context e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP#Computing

Comment: @aneroid Which definition are you disagreeing with?

Comment: @ RobbieDee I am disagreeing with your definition. Agreeing with @KarlForner's statement.

Comment: @aneroid What would be your definition of data dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You could go the complete opposite direction and call them by their technical name rather than their meaning and let ppl infer that -- You could call them [**`candidate keys`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) - which makes sense in a "pick the candidate of your choice" kinda way; and each candidate is unique* (or supposed to be).

Nomenclature issues tend to be fun when they're not total headaches :-)

Comment: I don't really understand your proposition, even after reading about candidate keys !

Comment: By opposite I meant - searching for technical vs. meaningful names - the Candidate Keys are values in the Lookup Table. Those are the values you actually pick from, in the tables they are referenced. So the `UserType.user_type_id` are Foreign keys for `User.user_type_id`, or to put it in a _meaningful_ way, `UserType.user_type_id` **and** `UserType.name` are Candidates for values in `User` (in those specific columns, `User.user_type_id` here). You asked what the canonical name for the `UserType` **table** should be -- and I'm saying I agree with @phillyd 's proposed term **`Lookup Table`**.

Comment: I thought candidate keys were columns in the Lookup table ?

Comment: Yes, the key is an index/rule for the column but what you're conceptually doing is making a link to a value in that column. Further exploration of "column" vs. "column value in a specific row" is just semantics. "Keys" are always columns and the usage is based on the values of that column. But you're looking for "something to call it" not get into technical definitions to confuse your users, right? Lookup Table/Column/Value suffice for such explanations. Otherwise, just call it a Parent Key/Parent Key Table.